# Show that this difference goes to zero,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, riemann-sum

$$\frac{1+\sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{N}}{N} - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{N} \to  0.$$

The hint given in the question is this: choose appropriate Riemann sums and estimate the approximation error.

My current work:

$$\frac{1+\sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{N}}{N} - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{N}$$

$$=: A_n =(\sum_{k=1}^N \sqrt{k}\frac{1}{N}) - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{N}$$

The first term is in the form of a Riemann sum, so letting N go to infinity, we see that mesh(p) goes to zero, for some partition p, which gives the (improper) Riemann integral, over the interval [1,N]:

$$\lim_{N->\infty}\int_1^N \sqrt{x}dx$$

Evaluation of the integral, without evaluating the limit, gives:

$$\frac{2}{3}N^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}$$

Then $$A_n = \frac{2}{3}N^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{2}{3} - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{N}$$

And this is where I am currently stuck.  The above equation is a little suspect, because I let N go to infinity to get the improper integral, while I did nothing with the $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{N}$ term -- and just included this term into the equation, since I feel it gets me a little closer to do some kind of approximation.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: A more interesting question would have been proving that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac kn}~-~\frac23\cdot n\bigg)=\frac12$

Comment: @Lucian: That might take a bit more than Riemann Sums. It can be done simply with the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, or some approximation thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the proper Riemann Sum is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/2}
&=n^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^n\color{#C00000}{\left(\frac kn\right)^{1/2}}\,\color{#00A000}{\frac1n}\\
&=n^{1/2}\int_0^1\color{#C00000}{x^{1/2}}\,\color{#00A000}{\mathrm{d}x}+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac23n^{1/2}+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
since the error estimate for the Riemann Sum is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\int_0^1\left|\,f'(x)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1n\int_0^12x^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about your 1/n term, and thought that it must be inside the summation, since the sum depends on n -- it depends on k, with n fixed.  I'll try once again, without studying the rest of your answer - hopefully, I can do it now.

Comment: I've tried for awhile now, @robjohn, and decided to check your solution again.  I couldn't get it on my own, but now I notice why (I think):  your k/n term becomes the x variable in the Riemann integral, but it is just a relabeling of k/n as x, and not a change of variable, which would get us an extra factor of n (so integration only gives 2/3).  Do you think the relabeling is no problem at all and doesn't have to be justified?  Thanks,

Comment: And, I notice that you didn't use an equality, but rather just an estimate -- which *is* what the problem is asking for... an estimate, so I think it's fine?

Comment: My integrand was:  $\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}$ dx, and I let u = $\frac{x}{n}$, so that n*du = dx ...

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include the approximation error. I will add that.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! :-)

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I don't understand the error estimate - how do you get the remainder term as something in $O(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: Are you using the Lagrange remainder?  Thanks,

Comment: I found some error estimate formulas just now that seems to use the mean value theorem.  Thanks so much for your help, @robjohn :-)

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I am getting that the error term is in O(1), because of the scaling by $\sqrt{n}$.  If I understood your work correctly, you're estimating the difference between the integral of $\sqrt{x}$ dx and the Riemann sum of $\sqrt{k/n}$, n is fixed.  The Riemann sum converges to a Riemann integral, with integrand $\sqrt{x/n}$, which goes to zero like 1/$\sqrt{n}$.  But this difference is scaled by $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: ...so that we really have (2/3)$\sqrt{n}$ - O(1)

Comment: (Unless you did some sort of decomposition of the Riemann sum into an integral + error term in some way that I don't really see...)

Comment: @LebronJames: The error formula says that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^{1/2}\,\frac1n =\int_0^1x^{1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x+O\left(\frac1n\right)$$ Multiply both sides by $n^{1/2}$ and we get $$n^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^{1/2}\,\frac1n =n^{1/2}\int_0^1x^{1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)$$

Comment: Hi @robjohn, is it ok to switch from the discrete variable k/n to the continuous variable x?  I feel like it k/n should be replaced with x/n in the Riemann integral.  I'm thinking of how the Riemann sum of log(n) converges to the integral of log(x).

Comment: Or does something like the Riemann sum of log(kn) converge to the Riemann integral of log(x), and *not* log(xn)?  I am a little confused with going from a discrete variable to a continuous variable...

Comment: @LebronJames: The whole point of using a Riemann Sum, is that we break an interval into $n$ pieces and approximate the integral on each small segment by a rectangle. When we do that in this case, $x$ becomes $\frac kn$ and $\mathrm{d}x$ becomes $\frac1n$

Comment: Ah, I think I finally got it.  Thanks so much for your help and patience, @robjohn :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you partition the interval $[0,N]$ to $N$ equal length subintervals, then those subintervals all have length $1$. Not $1/N$ as you seem to think.

I think that you are expected to observe that the sum
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{N}}\,\frac{\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt{N}}N
$$
is a Riemann sum related to the definite integral
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt x\,dx.
$$

In other words, scale everything by a factor of $\sqrt{N}$.

Standard error estimate available for all increasing functions is good enough unless I made a mistake.

Comment: Hi @JyrkiLahtonen, your first paragraph was very helpful.  I was indeed mistaken about how to interpret sub-interval lengths.  Can I keep my Riemann sum, with sub-interval length of 1/N, (N is fixed, so interval lengths are equal), and then the total length of the interval is N * 1/N = 1.  Which then, letting N go to infinity, gives the Riemann integral from 0 to 1, exactly the integral you gave -- but I didn't scale by a factor of $1/ \sqrt{N}$, since I feel that after this scaling, we are no longer looking at the original difference, $A_n$ ...

Comment: That's right. We scaled the difference by a factor of $1/\sqrt N$ as well. This is something you need to keep in mind in the end. That is, after you have estimated the difference between this Riemann sum and this integral.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with Stolz-Cesaro. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{1/2}.$ We are looking at

$$\frac{S_n -(2/3)n^{3/2}}{n}.$$

S-C says to look at

$$(n+1)^{1/2}+ (2/3)[n^{3/2} - (n+1)^{3/2}].$$

By the MVT, the second term equals $-c_n^{1/2},$ where $c_n \in (n,n+1).$ So we have

$$(n+1)^{1/2}-c_n^{1/2} = \frac{n+1-c_n}{(n+1)^{1/2}+c_n^{1/2}},$$

which is positive and less than $1/ (n+1)^{1/2} \to 0.$